# Sending Data in Aeroplane Mode

Tags: iphone

I am developing a chronometer app for iPhone which will used by the drivers in races. There will be a countdown. If user receives any call, in that case, the countdown will be paused. so I thought if user run his iPhone in Aeroplane mode, then he will not receive any call. But my problem is that, User will also have to send the data to the server during the race. But in aeroplane mode, it can't be done. I thought that user can divert the calls, it may work but is there any other better way for this or this is the only way? If I am not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way then with the divert calls, you will need to be connect to the cellular network to send/receive data. On GSM G3 connection you can send data and place a phone call at the same time, on verzions CDMA G3 network you can't.